# Catching "stack overflow" error returns "Null"

Tags: java, exception, recursion, null, try-catch

To demonstrate recursion and its drawback of using up stack space. I wrote below code. I found it return the anticipated error ("java.lang.StackOverflowError") when N is very large(like 100000). Then I tried to catch this specific error using the class given below and subsequent driver class. However Netbeans IDE returns "null" as shown in below result:

> Caught stack Overflow error: null
>
> The factorial of log of 100000 is 68687.75095683799
>
> Direct calculation 1051299.221899134
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Is there a way to return the actual error ? Could somebody help me on what I am doing wrong ?

```
package recursiondemo;

import static java.lang.Math.log;

/** This class demonstrates the recursion with calculation of the value log(N!)
 *  log(N!) = log(N*(N-1).....3*2*1) = log(N) + log (N-1) + ......log(3) + log (2) + log(1)
 * @author =
 */
public class logRecursion implements recursionInterface {
    //private int localCounter = 0;
    
    public logRecursion(){

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param localCounter
     * @return
     */
    //@Override
    public double directCalculation(int localCounter){
        double result = 0.0;
        int loopCounter = localCounter;
        
        while ( loopCounter >=1) {
            result += log(loopCounter);
            --loopCounter;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public double calculation(int localCounter) throws Exception{
        
        if (localCounter == 1) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        
        if (localCounter <= 0 ) {
            throw new Exception("Factorials are not defined for the input given");
        }
        try {
            return log(localCounter) + calculation(localCounter - 1); // Recursion
        }
        catch (StackOverflowError e) {
        System.err.println("Caught stack Overflow error: " +  e.getMessage());
        }
        return 0.0; // This is an arbitrary return value to avoid compile time error of no return parameter. So this return value is meaning less
    }
        
}

package recursiondemo;

/**
 * Driver class
 * @author
 */
public class RecursionDemo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here
        logRecursion test;
        test = new logRecursion();
        System.out.println("The factorial of log of " + args[0] + " is " + test.calculation(Integer.parseInt(args[0]))); // Recursion
        System.out.println("Direct calculation " + test.directCalculation(Integer.parseInt(args[0])) ); // Direct calculation
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Not sure if a StakOverflowError does have a message. Moreover, the println in the catch clause will most likely cause another StackOverflowError.

Comment: @Henry why? If catch block is being executed, it means that try block has been done for, and that the function was completed (successfully or not) and is off the stack.

Comment: @ Henry , make sense as now the stack space is blown.

Comment: Anything that carries **Error** in its name should **not** be catched. You just ran out of stack space; but your code says "I don't care about that". Seriously, what do you expect to happen? You drove the JVM into an error state, now what?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino the catch is in the recursive function itself. So just the top most incarnation is removed from stack when it is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `StackOverflowError` doesn't have a message (which is often the case for exceptions thrown by the runtime environment). That's why your log statement prints `null`. Note that this is not an exception/error you would normally want to catch.

Anyway, if you want to log a more meaningful message to the console, just use the error's `toString()` method, which will return its class name (+ the detail message, if there is one):

```
System.err.println("Caught stack Overflow error: " +  e);
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it and returned the expected exception.